# How do you find the length of a string in V+

Tags: string, v+

If i have a string say:

```
$msg = "This is a string"
```

How do i find the length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `LEN`:

```
$msg = "This is a string"
TYPE LEN($msg)
```

Output:

> . 16